# Check if a value in an array changed it is not repeated. knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an array of task's.

```
var task = function(name){
    var self = this;
    self.taskTitle = ko.observable(name);
 };

function taskViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable('');
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addTask = function (){
       self.tasks.push(new task(self.title());
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<td>
   <span data-bind='text: taskTitle, visible: !editing(), click: $root.editItem'></span>
   <input data-bind='visible: editing, selectAndFocus: editing, value: taskTitle, hasFocus: editing'>
</td>
```

So, when you touch the span it will convert to an input having the value of task Title so you can change it. I want to validate that that change of value it's not repeated in the array.

All my tasks are in the observable array tasks.

Thanks for the help

Comment: One possible way is to use knockout's subscribe function. Basically you'll subscribe to 'taskTitle' and every time it changes you check if the array has the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw9B2/626/).

```
function task(name, parent){
    var upArray = parent;
    var self = this;
    self.taskTitle = ko.observable(name);
    self.oldCopy = ko.observable(name);
    self.editing= ko.observable(false);
    self.editNow = function(){
        self.editing(true);
    };
    self.blurOut = function()
    {
        self.editing(false);
    };
    self.oldCopy.subscribe(function(newVal){
        if (upArray.tasks)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < upArray.tasks().length; i++){
                if (upArray.tasks()[i].taskTitle() === newVal){
                    self.oldCopy(self.taskTitle());
                    return;
                }
            }
            self.taskTitle(newVal);
        }
    });

}

function taskViewModel(){
    var self = this;   
    self.title = ko.observable('Title');
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([new task('oak', this)]);
    self.tasks.push(new task('tree', this));

}

 ko.applyBindings(new taskViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Its pretty sloppy but its the quick and dirty version. Notice the subscribe where I get the new value every time its changed. That's where I would compare the array with the new given value. Subscribe is basically an observer on that variable.